# SVN to Git - smooth migration

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I want to smoothly migrate with team to **Git**, now we use **SVN**.

Is it possible to cross post commits?

For example, employee A post to **SVN**, after that changes posts to Git repository and vice versa.

(As I see:
I know we should resolve conflicts, but if we resolve conflicts in one repo maybe we can force push/rewrite changed files in another repo head (why not?). 
Except cases when two repos have different head state (head + 2 new commits, head + 5 new commits), but it's very rare case, my plan to install repos on one server and maybe lock repos before one post commit to another (after one receive commit), I think it should work pretty fast).

Or if it's not possible, can we post commits from git to svn (because now app builds from SVN repo).

PS: I'm not super **Git/SVN** user, I know best solution - one-time migration to **Git**, but if I could I did. 
So if you have similar experience please advise what's better way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

There are several Git to/from Subversion bridges, designed for your use-case. Among the commonly cited ones:

- GitHub is Git-centric but offers an SVN access to its repo. This is tied to GitHub, so not an option if you don't want to use GitHub.
- [SubGit](http://www.subgit.com/) which is free (not "free software", but free of charges) for open-sources and academic use, but not for commercial use.

I'm not aware of a free software solution that would fit this need properly.

[git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) is another option, but it's meant to be client-side: it allows you to use Git as a client to access SVN repositories. The typical use-case is when you are *not* doing a migration, and some individuals still want to use Git. It works very well for this use-case.

It's probably possible to hack a server-side solution based on git-svn, but I wouldn't recommend it: most likely you'll end up with a buggy solution and people will blame Git and the migration for any issue they get, and they'll want to come back to SVN.

Answer (score 2):

> For example, employee A post to SVN, after that changes posts to Git repository and vice versa.
>   ...
>   Or if it's not possible, can we post commits from git to svn (because now app builds from SVN repo).

You can do it. git has svn "adapter". you simply need to add git svn before your commands

Read more about it here: [git-svn](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn)